# Both the light and fan switch turn on the fan. Neither turns on the light

Tags: ceiling-fan

We bought a house that has a Casablanca W-32 fan switch and a Kichler fan. Both the fan and light button on the switch turn on the fan only. Nothing turns on the light. The reverse button also turns on the fan, but not in reverse. I changed the round LED light bulb and this did not make the light go on. I checked the wiring at the switch, and the wiring at the fan, and it is all done correctly I think. I did switch the black/white striped wires around in the switch and it made no difference. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Update: It appears it was a faulty switch box. I replaced it (along with the remote receiver in the fan) and it works perfectly. I wired everything as before. I'm posting photos even though it is resolved.

[image: Switch]

[image: Fan]

Comment: Can you post photos of how things are wired?

Comment: There might be two separate cables connecting the switches box to the fan box. Each cable would have a a black, a white, and a ground. Maybe ihe connection at  the fan both blacks are connected to the black lead which goes to the fan and nothing is connected to the light (blue lead).

Comment: But there may be only one cable connecting the switches box with the fan box, and if so it would be expected to have two switched hots (black and red), one neutral (white) and one ground. Sounds like both switched hots are connected to the fixture lead for the fan (usually black) and and nothing is connected to the lead for the light. One switched hot is supposed to be connected to the hot for the light (usually blue colored).

Comment: Post your resolution as an answer and I'll give it a +1